# Adding a captcha plugin for comments in the site

Tags: captcha

Hi, I am new to WordPress.I need to add captcha in my site just before the comments section. Wherever there is comments, I need to display the captcha. I do not have a form. How can I do it?

Comment: should I add any code on the comments.php file?

Comment: A captcha is pointless without a form. This doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are a lot of solution for this. [Simply a *google*](https://www.google.com/search?q=adding+captcha+in+wordpress+comment) could answer you the whole. And also [WordPress plugin repository](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=captcha) could help you. But to pinpoint, you can use Plugins easily. Try anyone of them:

- [**Captcha** — WordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/captcha/screenshots/)
- [**SI CAPTCHA Anti-Spam** — WordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/si-captcha-for-wordpress/screenshots/)
- *more...*

And also, [**Akismet**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugins/Akismet) is a very good plugin to get the spam out of a WordPress site. And the good news is: Akismet is freely distributed with WordPress.

Comment: I tried a lot, but all that I am getting is captcha for a comment form. But I actually need is a captcha for comments only. My site does not have a form

Comment: I'm afraid, thing is not clear to me. Where there's no comment form, how the comments are gathered? And if there are the comments already, why do you need a captcha for *already-posted-comments*?

Comment: oh sry, can you just tell me where to put the captcha code in twenty thirteen theme

Comment: I think what [the plugin1](http://wordpress.org/plugins/captcha/screenshots/) and [the plugin2](http://wordpress.org/plugins/si-captcha-for-wordpress/screenshots/) are suggesting is just a check-mark on the right thing, it will automatically do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this plugin for adding captcha in your site wherever you want inside any form [Really Simple Captcha](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-captcha/)